# SQL select sum from other table as a column via junction table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have 2 regular Tables "Tasks" and "Employees" and one junction table EmployeeTasks simplified they look like this

**Tasks**

- TaskID
- ProjectID
- Duration

**Employee**

- EmployeeID
- EmployeeName

**EmployeeTasks**

- EmployeeID
- TaskID

I am trying to find a tsql query that based on a common project ID would deliver a summary of the total time spent and number of tasks done by each employee. Similar to this:

```
"Employee" | "Number of Tasks" | "Time Spent"
----------------------------------------
John       |        5          |  123
Sam        |        4          |   72
```

Comment: no zeroes thanks! Hehe no homework I just don't usually work with databases and am trying to get my head around SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT E.EmployeeName, COUNT(T.TaskID) AS [Number of Tasks], SUM(T.Duration) as [Time Spent]
FROM Employee E, EmployeeTasks ET, Tasks T
WHERE ET.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID AND ET.TaskID = T.TaskID
GROUP BY E.EmployeeName
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 Select EmployeeName, 
      Count(et.TaskId) NumTasks,
      Sum(T.Duration) TimeSpent
  From Employees E
     Left Join (EmployeeTasks eT Join Tasks T 
                   On T.TaskId = eT.TaskId)
        On eT.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId 
  Where ProjectId = @ProjectId
  Group By EmployeeName
```

and this will do it for all employees-Project combinations

```
  Select EmployeeName, ProjectId, 
      Count(et.TaskId) NumTasks,
      Sum(T.Duration) TimeSpent
  From Employees E
     Left Join (EmployeeTasks eT Join Tasks T 
                   On T.TaskId = eT.TaskId)
        On eT.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId 
  Group By EmployeeName, ProjectId
```

Answer (score 0):

Note this is different if you need to show time for an employee who has no tasks.

```
SELECT Count(TaskID) as NumOfTasks, Sum(Duration) as TimeSpent
FROM Employee 
INNER JOIN EmployeeTasks on Employee.EmployeeID = Tasks.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN Tasks on EmployeeTasks.TaskID = Tasks.TaskID
WHERE ProjectID = @ProjectID
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

If you want the employee name you join this as a sub-select

```
SELECT EmployeeName, NumOfTasks, TimeSpent
FROM Employees 
INNER JOIN (insert select here) TaskSummary on Employees.EmployeeID = TaskSummary.EmployeeID
```